# How to get byte of file in Android

Tags: java, android, file, byte

In my application i want read **first 16 character** of file!
I write below codes but for this `byte[ ]` just show me **43**!
I want show me first **16 character of bytes**.

**My codes :**

```
String inputFile = getRootDirPath(context) + "/" + "girnmqlyv0.pdf";
File file = new File(inputFile);
                try {
                    byte[] fileBye = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
                    Log.e("FileByte", ""+fileBye[16]);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Show me this message in `logcat` :

```
E/FileByte: 43
```

How can i get fisrt 16 character of file?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to read a [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF) file. PDF is a binary file format, it does not contain text in a format that's easy to read. What output do you expect?

Comment: `byte[] fileBye = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file)`. Change the function call to `byte[] fileBye = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file, 16);` And post the adapted code for that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a String from the first 16 bytes, use this instead of `"+fileBye[16]`:

```
Log.e("FileByte", new String(fileBye, 0, 16));
```

Note that this converts the first 16 **bytes** into a string according to the default character encoding, which is UTF-8 on Android. If the text in the file contains non-ASCII characters, 16 bytes will not be converted to 16 characters.

---

To extract the first 16 bytes as a byte array, you can use:

```
byte[] first16 = Arrays.copyOfRange(fileBye, 0, 16);
```

Or you can read only the first 16 bytes, instead of the entire file:

```
byte[] first16 = new byte[16];
try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inputFile)) {
    in.read(first16);
}
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, but show me such as this : `��>h[iZ�T�w0=�` :|

Comment: That's what's written in the file. If you open the file in a text editor what do you see?

Comment: I want store this 16 characters into byte[] for use init vector for decode with AES ad CBC

Comment: can you help me how can i store this 16 characters into byte[] ?

Comment: Ah so you don't want characters or strings after all. See the update

Comment: `I want store this 16 characters into byte[]` You have them already in that byte array! You do not need anything more.

Answer (score 0):

define a size to your array like this `byte[] bytes = new byte[size];`

in your case the size is 16